# In Code behind, get all checked values of dynamically created CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, webforms, controls, checkboxlist

In ASP.NET Web Forms, how would I get all checked items of a CheckBoxList that was programmatically created.  Assume that I only know the ID of the CheckBoxList.

My guess is something like:

```
var checklist = Find.Control(id);
foreach (ListItem item in checklist)
{
    if (item.Checked)
    {
        ..Do something
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to grab the CheckBoxList correctly.

Edit: I posted the way I solved it below.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done many different ways. Check out these great links below. The basic way would be to use Page.FindControl('') and loop through the control.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1134905.aspx

http://devsushi.com/2007/01/19/aspnet-dynamic-controls-part-4/

http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/HTML-Control/HTMLTextAreagetinputvalueVBnet.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hm... so I got it to work perhaps by a roundabout way.

```
string checkBoxName = "";
string val = "";
for (int j = 0; j < numBoxes; j++)
{
    checkBox = checkBoxListId + "$" + j;
    val += Request[checkbox] + ",";
}
```

I had to use the number of items in the CheckBoxList, then loop through and get the value of each checkbox individually, using its name and `Request[]`.  Because of the weird way that CheckBoxList is rendered, I had to manually recreate the checkbox name with "$" and the number.